# how to get HTML table dynamic rows using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch the html table data using vba, 
HTML table contains search box based on search box input, table will filter
 the rows. But my code fetching first row of not filtered table data

**Html code**

[image]
**vba code**

```
Set div_tag = ie.document.getElementById("list-wrapper")
        Set Table = div_tag.getElementsByTagName("TABLE") 'Table
         Set tRows = Table(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")




 For lngTable = 0 To Table.Length - 1
        For lngRow = 2 To tRows.Length - 1
        'For lngCol = 0 To Table(0)(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1

            Set tCells = tRows(lngRow).getElementsByTagName("td") '.Item(2)
            MsgBox (tCells.Item(2).innerText & "....." & tCells.Item(7).innerText & "....")
           'Next lngCol

        Next lngRow
       ' ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
    Next lngTable
```

looking for solution

Thanks...

Comment: Is there an URL to go with this you can provide? And maybe explain a little more the expected result. I am pretty certain this is not a duplicate of the linked question as  you are attempting to interact with the page and then grab the table of filtered results. The linked question is after a single value from an existing table. Neither given answer there will do what you are after.

Comment: Please include HTML using the snippet tool available via [edit] and are the rows currently shown in the image the ones you are after?